# Can't Run Tests in VS2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, mstest, visual-studio-express

Has anybody run into the following error when trying to run unit tests in Visual Studio Express 2012 For Web?:

> MSTestAdapter could not discover the test because the classic mode helper is not available. If a TestSettings file has been selected, unselect it and try again.

I had a solution in Visual Studio 2012 RC which contains a couple of applications, several class libraries, and a couple of unit test projects.  When Visual Studio 2012 was released, I changed over to Express For Web.  Everything's compiling and running fine, but any time I try to run unit tests I get the above error.

As a test, I unloaded the unit test projects and removed the TestSettings file and added a new unit test project with one test, which is a simple true assert.  However, the error persists.

Googling hasn't turned up much of anything for me.  A few related posts on various sites, but nothing substantial just yet.  (Maybe somebody else has had more luck?)  It looks like the test framework is failing before it even tries to invoke MSTest, but what's also curious is that I can't find `mstest.exe` on the machine.

Has anybody run into this and solved it?  I suppose I could move to NUnit (though their website isn't responding, which doesn't instill a lot of confidence in the project) or something of that nature, though I'd prefer to keep the number of tools down where possible.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you managed to run the tests?

Comment: I have found the problem and have explained the solution in my blog: http://dailywebtips.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/visual-studio-2012-express-error.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I have deleted some test settings files and it is working now.
Files to be removed:

- Local.testsettings
- SOLUTIONNAME.vsmdi
- TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings

Steps:

- Remove all 3 files from the solution
- Delete all 3 files from the solution folder
- Close the solution in VS12 and reopen it

http://dailywebtips.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/visual-studio-2012-express-error.html

Comment: Interesting.  This time deleting the `TestSettings.TestSettings` file and re-opening Visual Studio did the trick.  (I don't have either of those other files.)  Though now Visual Studio is failing to "Rebuild Solution" because it can't seem to follow the project references.  Buggy all around, it seems.  Either way, this got the test project running.  Thanks!

Comment: Had a similar issue in VS2013 and this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic answer, AndreCruz!  Helped me a lot!
However, when I tried to run the tests, it complained with :

> Unable to set TestContext property for the class
>   WavverTests.UnitTest1.  Error: System.ArgumentException: Object of
>   type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestFramework.TestContextImplementation'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext'.

I tried changing types as the error seems to suggest - as if the namespaces have changed.
But that didn't work, and gave an ever more obscure error.

Instead, delete this property!
For me, deleting the TestContext property solved the issue.

Hope this helps someone else.